# ScalaTest with mocked object

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalatest, scalamock

I found some simple examples, but nothing works.

a model:

```
class Product() {
  var price: Int = 0
  var stock: Int = 0

  def addPrice(price: Int): Int = {
    this.price = price
    this.price
  }

  def addStock(qty: Int): Int = {
    this.stock += qty
    this.stock
  }
}
```

and my test class

```
classProductSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with MockFactory with OneInstancePerTest {
  val m = mock[Product]

  // suites (test examples)
  inAnyOrder {
   (m.addPrice _).expects(40).returns(40).once
   inSequence {
     (m.addStock _).expects(20).returns(20).once
     (m.addStock _).expects(10).returns(30).once
   }
  }

  // tests
  it should "set price" in {
    assert(m.addPrice(40) == 40)
  }

  it should "add new qty. Step 1" in {
    assert(m.addStock(20) == 20)
  }

  it should "add new qty. Step 2" in {
    assert(m.addStock(10) == 30)
  }
}
```

Every time, the error is:

```
Expected:
  inAnyOrder {
     inAnyOrder {
     <mock-1> Product.addPrice(40) once (never called - UNSATISFIED)
    ...
  }
}
```

If I run only one suite and one assert, it works:

```
(m.addPrice _).expects(40).returns(40).once
// tests
it should "set price" in {
  assert(m.addPrice(40) == 40)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain the above code. The `inAnyOrder` section, defines assertions, for all tests. That means, that in each and every test in the suite, you should call exactly once to:

1. `m.addPrice(40)`
2. `m.addStock(20)`
3. `m.addStock(10)`

while 2 must come before 3. Therefore, each test fails due to lack of 2 calls. For example, the test:

```
it should "add new qty. Step 1" in {
  assert(m.addStock(20) == 20)
}
```

fails with the message:

```
Expected:
inAnyOrder {
inAnyOrder {
    <mock-1> Product.addPrice(40) once (never called - UNSATISFIED)
    inSequence {
    <mock-1> Product.addStock(20) once (called once)
    <mock-1> Product.addStock(10) once (never called - UNSATISFIED)
    }
}
}

Actual:
<mock-1> Product.addStock(20)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: ProductSpec at (ProductSpec.scala:20)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Unsatisfied expectation:
```

Because 1 and 3 were not satisfied.

If you'll try a test like:

```
it should "set price" in {
  assert(m.addPrice(40) == 40)
  assert(m.addStock(20) == 20)
  assert(m.addStock(10) == 30)
}
```

it will pass.
Please note that if you change the order of 2 & 3, the same test will fail.

Comment: great explanation!
The only thing i feel could be added is the link to the docs: https://scalamock.org/user-guide/sharing-scalatest/

Comment: yah, thanks, I understand better now. I founded another example using AnyWordSpec and MockitoSugar, where I realised that the assertion is before the test. So simple and so complicate in same time :)))